# How to turn off all the sounds in unity on click of button

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine

```
public void Click(){
    changeState();
}
private void changeState(){
    isClicked = !isClicked;
    if(isClicked)       myBtn.image.sprite = Play;
    else myBtn.image.sprite = Pause;
}
```

I have attached the above code to change the button image.
and now how can I turn off all the sounds.
Any help would be great.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the suggestion in first answer, you can also disable the
audio-listener in your scene. Or, if you can access all the audio-sources
you can stop each one of them.

```
public AudioListener audioListener;
public List<AudioSource> audioSources;


void OnMouseDown() {
    foreach(AudioSource audioSorce in audioSources) {
        audioSorce.Stop();
    }
    /*
    if(audioListener != null) {
        audioListener.enabled = false;
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can turn of all sound in Unity by pausing the `AudioListener`.

```
 AudioListener.pause = true;
```

If you want it to toggle each time the button is clicked, you could use:

```
AudioListener.pause = !AudioListener.pause;
```

Finally, if all you want to do is to reduce the volume of all sound in your game:

```
float yourVolume = 1f;
AudioListener.volume = yourVolume;
```

Comment: I'm able to select only one answer :). Happy coding !!